# Регистрация в Google Cloud Messaging запросами

Tags: c#, android, request, google-cloud-messages

По воле случая необходимо реализовать регистрацию и принятие сообщений через GCM чистыми запросами. Регистрация и получение registerId такого вида - `f-6NNCK8ofQ:APA91bG7jidNV0GXPAboq1-i43qEfdMIl41atSlYw5x4B9puWACi3AYXCfe8-__b1Bfqo4kXCX-JQ2C6aRgigmmyaHwyFfWMbksqv3Z1bUge6XZYVDMe_KXOS_LGpaXFlFO399GWsBRO` посредством запроса на `https://android.clients.google.com/c2dm/register3` реализована. Но, сообщения, отправленные по этому registerId не приходят, т.к. штатный GCM не открыл сокет для принятия сообщений. Каким образом можно принимать сообщения по этому registerId без использования штатного GCM(в своем продукте под windows)? Причем можно даже их не читать, просто чтобы они куда-то уходили без ошибки при попытке отправить.

Comment: токен, всмысле registerId который гугл возвращает? Объявить в сети, всмысле, чтобы пуши отсылались на девайс?

Comment: Да и да. Сложность в том, что приложение, которое принимает пуши и сервер, который шлет пуши - не мои. Но когда я шлю полученный registerId на сервер и пытаюсь отослать пуш на устройство - мне приходит ошибка(сервера, а не gcm). То есть при попытке отослать пуш происходит ошибка, хотя устройство зарегистрировано.

Comment: То есть на сервере хранится этот registerId, привязанный к пользователю, но при отправке пуша gcm выдает ошибку. Тогда надо знать что за ошибка именно, скорей всего запрос сформирован неправильно

Comment: Запрос сформирован правильно 100%. Проблема в том, что, судя по всему, GCM служба на андроиде открывает соединение со своим сервером и принимает сообщения, но я как раз хочу то же самое сделать, но без андроида.И сервер пытается отправить сообщение, но соединение не открыто(или не зарегистрировано), вследствие чего происходит ошибка отправки. Вот я бы и хотел узнать как мне открыть это соединение(можно даже не принимать пуши, просто чтобы они уходили в никуда без ошибки)

Comment: Как работает GCM? Сначала устройство регистрируется на сервере GCM и получает registerId (токен), отправляет этот токен на свой сервер (сторонний), этот токен сохраняется на этом сервере в БД. Затем, при отправке сообщений, сервер (сторонний) отправляет сообщения на сервер GCM, указывая все токены, на которые нужно отправить. Приложение на устройстве в сервисе ловит сообщение от GCM и выводит нотификейшен. Куда Вы хотите влезть?